# Scala project with maven in IntelliJ does not compile

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I created a `scala` project and included `Maven` framework in it. After that the code doesn't compile and hence when I run the file, I end up getting the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.scala.TestSpark
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark **scala** directory as **Sources Root**.

[image: Mark scala directory as Source Root]

Comment: Thanx a lot.. This was pissing me off.